# Differentiability of the function:$g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $$g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$ with $f$ continuously differentiable($\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$) and $f'(0)=0$.

> Then, is $g$ differentiable on $\mathbb{R^2}$? Specifically, does $g(0,0)$  and $f(0)$ have a role to play?

Comment: What is $g(0)$? Did you mean $g(0,0)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks. edited the post. please check now.

Comment: hai Vidyarthi, how is your preparation going?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan yes, preparation is terrible. Just randomly glancing at previous papers and wonderstuck at the level of problems. How is your preparation? And have you applied for any other exams-GATE, JAM, CSIR,TIFR,etc.?

Comment: @vidyarthi yes. I am also doing the same. I have GATE exam too. I have given CSIR and TIFR.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan which books are you referring to?

Comment: I have referred standard books during my course. @vidyarthi. what I lack was problem-solving skill. are you going to any coaching?currently, I am busy with my job. I am teaching Mathematical for UG Physics students. planning to do previous year papers. can you create a chat with me. let's share solutions there.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan yes, let us start a chat and share some solutions. CSIR and TIFR were both deadly for me. I failed TIFR and CSIR is almost out of hand. Let us discuss more. Invite me for a chat.

Comment: @vidyarthi me too will fail. Let's start.

Comment: @vidyarthi I will create a chat room for CSIR. please join

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/72440/csir-tifr-isi-nbhm?tab=general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For $g(x,y)$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ we have to see if
>   $$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

We have,

$$g_x(0,0)=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0,0)}{h}=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(|h|)-f(0)}{h}=0$$

$$g_y(0,0)=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(0,k)-g(0,0)}{k}=\lim _{k\to 0}\frac{f(|k|)-f(0)}{k}=0$$

Since,  $f'(0)=0$ we would have  $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0))}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim _{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}=f'(0)=0$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

i.e., $g(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: How did you calculate this $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$?

Comment: By polar co-ordinate. Right? $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})-f(0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{f(\sqrt{r^2})-f(0)}{\sqrt{r^2}}$$

Comment: since $f$ is differentiable at zero. It's limit is zero. Right?

Comment: set $t=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$

Comment: okay. Thanks :)